# Vector with custom objects: crash when I want to use one received with .at method

Tags: c++

I have a class named CConfig, I'm creating new object:

```
std::vector< CConfig > docs;

CConfig newfile( "somefile.xml", "root" );
printf("%s", newfile.GetTagValue( "servername" )); // this works
docs.push_back( newfile );
```

When I'm getting this object with .at method

```
CConfig file = docs.at(0);
printf("%s", file.GetTagValue( "servername" )); // this crashes
```

Where's the problem?

(im sorry if formatting is wrong but currently I don't use javascript because my bandwidth is ended and max speed is 1kb/s so I'll try to fix it later)

CConfig.h:

```
class CConfig
{
    TiXmlDocument       m_doc;
    TiXmlElement*       m_pRoot;
    bool                m_bIsLoaded;

public:
                    CConfig                     ( void ) {};
                    CConfig                     ( const char * pszFileName, const char * pszRootName );
                    ~CConfig                    ( void ) {};

const char*         GetTagValue                 ( const char * pszTagName );
const char*         GetTagAttribute             ( const char * pszTagName, const char * pszAttributeName );
TiXmlElement*       GetRootElement              ( void )    { return m_pRoot; };
bool                IsAvailable                 ( void )    { return m_bIsLoaded; };
};
```

CConfig.cpp

```
#include "CConfig.h"

CConfig::CConfig( const char * pszFileName, const char * pszRootName )
{
    m_bIsLoaded = m_doc.LoadFile( pszFileName );
    if( m_bIsLoaded )
        m_pRoot = m_doc.FirstChildElement( pszRootName );
}

const char * CConfig::GetTagValue( const char * pszTagName )
{
    if( m_bIsLoaded && m_pRoot )
    {
        TiXmlElement * element = m_pRoot->FirstChildElement( pszTagName );
        if( element )
            return element->GetText();
    }
}

const char * CConfig::GetTagAttribute( const char * pszTagName, const char * pszAttributeName )
{
    if( m_bIsLoaded && m_pRoot )
    {
        TiXmlElement * element = m_pRoot->FirstChildElement( pszTagName );
        if( element )
            return element->Attribute( pszAttributeName );
    }
}
```

I'm using tinyxml

Comment: I hope you realize this *begs* for the definition of `CConfig`. this smells like `CConfig` is violating the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming).

Comment: the problem is that you didn't tell us what `CConfig` is.

Comment: the prototypes aren't enough. Look, I expect your issue is that the class is storing a pointer to a string which gets `free`d or goes out of scope. But you're not posting the right code to narrow down / prove it.

Comment: Well that is the declaration at least. Any code for that constructor? Is that destructor *really* empty?

Comment: Side note: Both `GetTagValue()` and `GetTagAttribute()` have indeterminate return values if the item you're looking for is NOT present. Ask yourself what they return when `element` is NULL.

Comment: Great, that's what we needed :) Your issue is that `m_pRoot` is getting deleted because `m_doc` is deleted when your class goes out of scope. The copy (in the array) still has a pointer to the old one.

Comment: That would be, as suspected, a [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming) violation.

Comment: As @WhozCraig mentioned, not all execution paths in GetTagValue() and GetTagAttribute() return a value, including when element is null and when the condition `if( m_bIsLoaded && m_pRoot )` evaluates to false. Especially in this case if m_pRoot is null there is no return statement, which will return a valid "const char *" pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is with pointers to old memory. When you add an item to an array, it is copied. Later you leave that scope and the original is destroyed, but ask yourself where the pointer in your copy is pointing? Still to the first (now deleted) object's memory. Uh-oh.

The simplest fix (while avoiding large copy operations) is to make `m_doc` into a shared pointer (available in the standard in C++11, or via Boost in C++03). That will then handle everything for you rule-of-3 wise. And because the underlying memory won't move, `m_pRoot` will remain valid until the last copy has been deleted.

Comment: You could, instead, update the pointer to point to the new memory in the copy constructor and assignment operator, but because that would still mean doing an expensive copy of the document itself and you're using a parameter string to get the pointer in the first place (which you would need to store somehow; same memory issues apply), I don't recommend that. Same rough reasoning goes for just making `m_pRoot` into a non-pointer: you would end up with expensive copies.

Answer (score 2):

If copy-space is not an issue, then fix your Rule of Three violation by properly adding a copy constructor:

```
CConfig(const CConfig& obj) 
   : m_doc(obj.m_doc)
   , m_bLoaded(obj.m_bLoaded)
   , m_pRoot()
{
   if (m_bLoaded)
      m_pRoot = m_doc.GetRootElement();
}
```

An assignment operator is also likely in order, but if you don't need it, hide it by declaring it (but not implementing it) as `private` or use the C++11 `delete` attribute feature.

Interestingly enough, you don't even need the `m_bLoaded` member. A non-NULL root pointer can indicate your loaded-state, but that is a separate issue. This at least be enough to get you up and running.

Comment: don't forget assignment! edit: oh right, you did mention that… nevermind!

Comment: @Dave See second paragraph.

Comment: yeah I kind'a missed that. Anyway, I knew there was a reason I decided against this: `m_pRoot` isn't the root element: `m_pRoot = m_doc.FirstChildElement( pszRootName )`. It's based on one of the parameters. So to do this, he would still need to store that parameter. Since it's a C string, he's got the same issue again (although it wouldn't be difficult to wrap it in a `std::string`), unless it's possible to get that value out of the existing `m_pRoot`, which it might be. (also the expensive copy issue which you mentioned)

Comment: @Dave So long as TinyXml::TxmlDocument supports copy-construction (and it does), this will work as-designed. The copy target (our object being constructed) will set its own root pointer from its own document after the document itself was copied from the original. Either that, or I just misunderstood what you are talking about.

Comment: I agree that it will be a valid node, but `m_pRoot != m_doc.GetRootElement()`. It is, instead, the first element with a particular name. And that name is only known in the original constructor. It is not stored.

Comment: @Dave Ahhh. ok. *Now* I see, and yes, I *did* misunderstand you. you're absolutely right. I was falsely assuming the root element pointer was just that, the root element pointer from the doc. You're absolutely right. Keeping the element name as a member would work around that issue, as you said. Thank you!.

Comment: No problem. I think this shows that the variable needs a different name!

Comment: @Dave yeah, I was somewhat taken back when I scrolled back up to the source and saw what was *really* going on. I hope it was also clear why `m_bLoaded` isn't needed (a non-null `m_pRoot` is evidence enough of load-state). Anyway, +1 on your answer. nice catch.

Comment: Yeah, getting rid of `m_bLoaded` makes sense